# Access label of chapter / section / ... based on nesting depth

Tags: sectioning

I want to know how to get the label of the chapter/section/subsection/paragraph which my text is currently in. I don't mean the name of the section via `\nameref{}` or `\titleref{}` , nor the number `\ref{}`,  nor any `\label{}` related output.

I want to get the `\chaptername` and so on, but related to the current nesting depth, with only one command. Best combined with the babel package for international use. If this works a rearranging of sections/paragraphs is easier, because the labels get updated according to the heading they are in.

I can't provide a MWE, but here is something that comes quite close to what I mean. Note that the `\currentheadingname` command is the missing piece, which I am looking for.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{SomeChapter}
Greetings from this \currentheadingname

\section{SomeSection}
In this \currentheadingname \dots 

\subsection{SomeSubsection}
This \currentheadingname is about \dots
\end{document}
```

The desired result looks like:

1. SomeChapter

Greetings from this chapter

1.1. SomeSection

In this section ...

1.1.1. SomeSubsection

This subsection is about...

Is there such a command? Or any workaround?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't exists, but it can be defined.

We'll define it empty

```
\newcommand{\currentheadingname}{}
```

and redefine it for each sectioning command with the help of `\pretocmd` from the `etoolbox` package:

```
\pretocmd{\part}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{part\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{chapter\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{section\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subsection\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subsubsection\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{paragraph\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subparagraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subparagraph\xspace}}{}{}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xspace} 

\newcommand{\currentheadingname}{}

\pretocmd{\part}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{part\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{chapter\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{section\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subsection\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subsubsection\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{paragraph\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subparagraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{subparagraph\xspace}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{SomeChapter}
Greetings from this \currentheadingname

\section{SomeSection}
In this \currentheadingname \dots

\subsection{SomeSubsection}
This \currentheadingname is about \dots
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

In regards of `babel`, it unfortunately defines only `\partname` and `\chaptername`, so nothing to do for `\section` and so on.

---

### EDIT

A solution for "international use".

If you load `hyperref`, the following commands get defined: `\partautorefname`, `\chapterautorefname`, `\sectionautorefname`, etc. They change depending on the language loaded by `babel` (although not all `babel` languages are defined, only `afrikaans`, `english`, `french`, `german`, `italian`, `magyar`, `portuges`, `russian`, `spanish`, `vietnamese`).

So you can change the above definitions to

```
\pretocmd{\part}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\MakeLowercase{\partautorefname}\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\MakeLowercase{\chapterautorefname}\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\sectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subsectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subsubsectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\paragraphautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subparagraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subparagraphautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
```

Note `\MakeLowercase` for `\partautorefname` and `\chapterautorefname`, since they are defined capitalised.

The following MWE shows how to obtain current heading names in Italian:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\currentheadingname}{}

\pretocmd{\part}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\MakeLowercase{\partautorefname}\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\MakeLowercase{\chapterautorefname}\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\sectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subsectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subsubsectionautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\paragraphautorefname\xspace}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subparagraph}{\renewcommand{\currentheadingname}{\subparagraphautorefname\xspace}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{SomeChapter}
Greetings from this ``\currentheadingname''

\section{SomeSection}
In this ``\currentheadingname'' \dots

\subsection{SomeSubsection}
This ``\currentheadingname'' is about \dots

\subsubsection{SomeSubsubsection}
This is a ``\currentheadingname''.

\paragraph{SomeParagraph}
This is a ``\currentheadingname''.

\subparagraph{SomeSubparagraph}
This is a ``\currentheadingname''.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1, although I'd rather not use `\xspace`.

Comment: +1, thanks for the quick and detailed answer! it's kind of a basic feature to me and i wonder, that it doesn't exist yet. Hopefully babel will add some `\sectionname` command in future to grab the localized names.